# Qt Creator Code File Refactoring

Tags: c++, refactoring, qt-creator

I was wondering if anyone know of a quick and easy way to refactor the code files in my QT Project using QTCreator? Specifically I am trying to organize my source files and Its a bit of a pain to have to go back into the project file and change the filepath for each file. Not to mention moving a dialog class is even worse (there are .ui files not included in the project but you have to change those too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only file renaming/moving support that is "integrated" (i.e. it updates your project file automatically) is using the active project pane with your file list, rightclick and select "rename", using "../../some/new/dir/name.cpp" to move your files. It will of course not update any #include statements, but will save you the trouble of modifying your .pro file manually. It also respects "git rename" etc...

Comment: Thanks this worked well. Not as nice as being able to drag and drop but hey it works.

Comment: Doesn't work for directories... Qt Creator is lacking in so many basic IDE features...

Comment: @Sebastian IMHO, renaming directories is a file manager function, really. IDEs are great at displaying, modifying, and debugging code.

Comment: @rubenvb I'd expect `#include`s and .pro files to be updated automatically during a file rename but then I guess I'm used to the world of Java and eclipse, where `#import`s are automatically updated whenever a package changes.

Comment: This doesn't work indeed (I tried with slashes, backslashes etc). I got "try using another name, with fewer characters or no punctuation marks". It does not except the dots...

Comment: Not posible anymore in QtCreator 4.8

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thats possible, moving files without ide support is a pain in the... :/